# Handling AsyncCallback<T>?

Tags: java, debugging, gwt, webkit, rpc

I have a class which checks for action of users, validate the data and call AsyncCallBack to determine whether it's a valid entry or not. I have used the same logic in two places one when user clicks "OK" and other one is "Enter". Code works fine by calling AsyncCallBack in one scenario.

My question is what would be the best way to debug ? know why it's not entering/calling AsyncCallBack.

```
     try
     {
     testService.validateForm( type, form, number, new AsyncCallback() 
     {

                            @SuppressWarnings( "synthetic-access" )
                            public void onFailure( Throwable caught )
                            {
                                System.out.println( " HELLO FAILURE " ); 
                            }

                            @SuppressWarnings( "synthetic-access" )
                            public void onSuccess( Object result )
                            {
                                System.out.println( " HELLO SUCCESS " ); 

                            }

                        } );
                    }
                    catch ( GenericException e )
                    {
                        // --e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println( " ----- Done -------" ); 
  }
```

I have used similar data in both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're running in DevMode, you won't see your System.out's.  Use GWT.log, as it will print to your DevMode console, and be stripped out automatically from the compiled javascript.

I would recommend debugging and putting break points on the server-side validateForm method, as well as breakpoints in both onSuccess and onFailure.  Also - make sure you're actually calling the method, so a breakpoint at testService.validateForm, too.

Comment: I did all possible experiment with debugging.  Breakpoint at  testService.validateForm determines it will about to call but it just look for type, form, number and skips new AsyncCallback( ) call and prints  ----- Done -------.

Comment: Hm.  One thing I've seen happen before is the compiler doens't appropriately add to the GWT cache when files change.  Have you tried deleting the gwt-unitCache folder and forcing GWT to recompile everything?